Why do my all of my Openpyxl operations take so long?
I'm manipulating data from an Excel data sheet 87MB large using Openpyxl and pandas but each one takes 10-30 minutes long.
I'm doing operations such as: deleting rows/columns, working out and printing mean, multiplying same cell in different sheets and outputting on a different sheet.
Example (took 20 minutes) :
book = 'file path' 
sheet1 = '1'  # Replace with your first sheet name
sheet2 = '2'  # Replace with your second sheet name

# Read the sheets into DataFrames
df1 = pd.read_excel(book, sheet_name=sheet1)
df2 = pd.read_excel(book, sheet_name=sheet2)

# Check if dimensions match
if df1.shape != df2.shape:
    raise ValueError("Sheets have different shapes")

I need to be able to read and write at the same time.
My end result and my operation don't need to be in an .xlsx file.

If your Excel file is 87MB on disk it's likely to need way more than that in RAM. Check your memory usage (you may be swapping). Also, consider multiprocessing although pickling the dataframes (i.e., the return value from the subprocess) might also be very time consuming

Can you benchmark it? Which part of the pipeline is taking the longest? If it's a transformation constraint and not I/O you may want to look into Spark or Polars, Pandas is singlethreaded and not super well optimized for large(r) datasets.

Why are you reading the same file twice?  That's gotta be quite inefficient.

Looks like a fairly extreme test just to check whether to worksheets have different sizes. Use two-processes, use read-only mode and things should be a bit faster.

@JohnGordon how can I make it read only once?

Call pd.read_excel() only once, and don't specify a sheet_name argument, so the resulting dataframe will have all the sheets.  Then you can refer to the specific sheet(s) you want, without having to read the file again.
